# Can I chain groupByKey calls on pair_rdd in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible in Pyspark to chain a `groupByKey()` call on a pair_rdd twice?

I have two levels of keys I want to group by before I aggregate by creating a special list of all values.

Here's my code. First `groupByKey()` call groups by the outer key and is then given to a map function in which I hope to turn the resultIterable object into a pair_rdd again so I can do the second `groupByKey()` and map my function to it.

(Since I'm reducing I guess I could also use `reduceByKey()` there?)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("test")\
    .master("local")\
    .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '4')\
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

def group_by(ws):
    L = ws[0]
    E = ...ws[1]... <-- Do something here to turn this from resultIterable to Pair_RDD
    rr = E.groupByKey().map(output_lists)
    return (L, rr)

def output_lists(ws):
    el = [e[0] for e in ws[1]]
    res = [ws[0]] + el
    return (ws[0], res)

input_data = (('A', ('G', ('xyz',))),
              ('A', ('G', ('xys',))),
              ('A', ('H', ('asd',))),
              ('B', ('K', ('qwe',))),
              ('B', ('K', ('wer',))))

data = sc.parallelize(input_data)

data = data.groupByKey().map(group_by)

print(data.take(5))
```

Now, is this even doable or do I need a different approach.

I know two other ways around:

- Concatenate both keys into one.
- Use a SparkSQL dataframe.

But I'm curious if there is a way with the above approach as I'm still learning Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can use tuples as keys in pair RDDs. Remapping my input data like this means only one `groupByKey()` is needed and the problem can be solved:

```
input_data = ((('A', 'G'), 'xyz'),
              (('A', 'G'), 'xys'),
              (('A', 'H'), 'asd'),
              (('B', 'K'), 'qwe'),
              (('B', 'K'), 'wer'))
```